# How to extract this JSON response

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to extract

1. the val from the first array
2. SVCNO and PATH from the second array

PROBLEM: However, I cannot seem to extract anything due to this error:

> This interface was deprecated in API level 22. Please use `openConnection()` instead. Please visit this webpage for further details.

These are my codes:

```
//where URL4 = http://www.onemap.sg/BusServiceAPI/Service1.svc/showRoute?token=489ce5de815c81c7fda85af3980e9b6258124ca68837e425a2b7373c2d869bbf9ea4ad5a4901fbce20da45b4e095643b&svc=39%7C1%3B85%7C1%3B169%7C1%3B811%7C1%3B851%7C1%3B852%7C1%3B854%7C1%3B854E%7C1%3B858%7C1%3B965%7C1%3B969%7C1

List<NameValuePair> URLparams4 = new LinkedList<NameValuePair();    
URLparams4.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_TOKEN, TOKEN));
URLparams4.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_SVC, joinBusDirAndSvc));

String paramString4 = URLEncodedUtils.format(URLparams4,"utf-8");
String url4 = BusShowRoute_URL + paramString4;

ResponseHandler<String>handler4 = new BasicResponseHandler();

HttpGet get4 = new HttpGet(url4);
HttpParams httpParameters4 = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient client4 = new DefaultHttpClient (httpParameters4);

try
{
    String response4 = client4.execute(get4,handler4);
    System.out.println("busesponse4= " + response4); //response array

    //convert result page into JSON Object
    JSONObject jsonResponse4= new JSONObject(response4);


    //get JSON Array
    jsArray_busRoute = jsonResponse4.getJSONArray(ATTR_BUSROUTE);
    System.out.print("jsArray_busRoute== " + jsArray_busRoute);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsArray_busRoute.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj_busRoute = jsArray_busRoute.getJSONObject(i);

        if (!obj_busRoute.has(ATTR_PAGECOUNT))
        {
            String val = obj_busRoute.getString(ATTR_VAL + i);
            System.out.print("val== " + val);
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the JSON response:**

```
{

"BusRoute":

      {

       "PageCount":[

          {
             "Val0":"TAMPINES INT,
              YISHUN TEMP INT"
          },
          {
             "Val1":"PUNGGOL TEMP INT,
              YISHUN TEMP INT"
          }
        ],
        "1":[
          {              
             "SVCNO":"39",
             "DRC":"1",
             "SQNO":"1",
             "DST":"0",
             "SBS":"75009",
             "EBS":"76059",
             "PATH":"40287.2481620079,37450.8849868048;
             40298.2076238208,37458.4535869379;
             40309.8456332916,37470.8674859032;
             40320.7077835361,37487.9365402292;                  
             40326.1859934768,37512.3384070937;
             40255.2463979153,37512.7719051559;
          }
        ]
     }
   }
```

**Thank you for helping!**

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Im using Eclipse Juno and the language is java

Comment: When I paste your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ it gives multiple errors. Are you sure that the JSON is correct?

Comment: yes i am very certain it is correct. i just went and paste the url in the link above and the web result says it is valid

Comment: Then add a java tag.

Comment: when does this error occur? on which statement execution?

Comment: your json format is wrong http://json.org/example.html

Comment: The error occurs at this statement.                                               jsArray_busRoute = jsonResponse4.getJSONArray(ATTR_BUSROUTE);

Comment: There is a misplaced double quote in your JSON, `"PATH":"40287....`  There is a starting quote there but no ending quote (which probably needs to be at the end of the list of numbers).